# Getting an error when logging out (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, apache, function, codeigniter

The user can log in fine, but when logout is pressed, an error appears. However, underneath the user is still logged in and when pressing the logout button again it actually logs out (but still with the error appearing above). Can anyone help? The error is below.

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/2/e/e/jessicarosedavidson.co.uk/httpd.www/codeigniter/application/models/Login_model.php:41)
>
> Filename: Session/Session_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 110
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /customers/2/e/e/jessicarosedavidson.co.uk/httpd.www/codeigniter/application/controllers/Login.php
>   Line: 59 Function: session_destroy
>
> File:
>   /customers/2/e/e/jessicarosedavidson.co.uk/httpd.www/codeigniter/index.php
>   Line: 292 Function: require_once

This is my Login Model

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class Login_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();
    }

    public function login($email, $password)
    {
    $this->db->where("email",$email);
    $this->db->where("password",$password);
    $query=$this->db->get("mvc_user");

     if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
    {
//add all data to session
$newdata = array(
  'user_id'  => $rows->id,
  'user_name'  => $rows->username,
  'user_email'    => $rows->email,
  'logged_in'  => TRUE,
);
}
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
return true;
}
return false;
}
}
?>
```

This is my controller Login.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('login_model');
    }


    public function index()
    {
         if(($this->session->userdata('user_name')!=""))
    {
            $this->welcome();
    }
    else    {
         $data['title']= 'Login';
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/nav');
            $this->load->view('login/signin', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
    }


    public function welcome()
    {

        $data['title']= 'Welcome';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/nav');
        $this->load->view('login/welcome', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }


     public function login()
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=$this->input->post('pass');


        $result=$this->login_model->login($email,$password);
        if($result) $this->welcome();
            else        $this->index();
    }

public function logout()
 {
  $newdata = array(
  'user_id'   =>'',
  'user_name'  =>'',
  'user_email'     => '',
  'logged_in' => FALSE,
  );
  $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata );
  $this->session->sess_destroy();
  $this->index();
  }


  }
  ?>
```

My views are in a file called login, in the views file. Any help will be really appreciated as i'm new to codeigniter!!

Comment: In the logout function you might try redirecting to the index instead of simply calling `$this->index();` because after `sess_destroy()` the Sessions class must be reloaded before you can make any calls to it. And that's the very first thing you do in `index()`.

Comment: On a side note, `$this->session->unset_userdata($newdata );` is not needed as `sess_destroy()` will dispose of all session data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by file.php

Delete extra spaces in your model at the end of the file , the number of lines in your model is 32 lines but the error says line 41 :) , delete the extra lines and everything will work fine!

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In you`public function welcome()` you are not checking for session. if you will access welcome page directly it will work and show your welcome screen even after logging out. you need to check in it also. 
for

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by file.php

you need to remove extra spaces from top of your controller and header. Not sure but you need to remove extra spaces on top of your view too.